# How can I prevent parallel inserts

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

Scenario A can insert rows in table A without any conditions

Scenarion B needs to read all rows from the table based on some column value (`SELECT FROM A WHERE col = 2`) and then inserts a row (or does nothing) back into table based on some calculation made on application side

If A inserts a new row with same `col` value (`2`) after scenario B reads table, but before scenario B inserts new row, then calculations were wrong and scenario B has inserted an invalid row

As far as I understand, even `Serializable` level can't detect that, since the row scenario B should insert is not calculated via SQL, but on application side

`col` is not a foreign key, so I can't lock a row somewhere else to prevent parallel inserts

I could re-read on application side after insert in scenario B, before commit. But scenario A insert still can be happen after re-read and before commit

The only solution I can think about is enumerate rows per `col`, each scenario will increment last value and use unique `(col, num)` index, some sort of optimistic lock. But then scenario A also needs to read the table before insert

Any other solution that can work here?

upd1: `Serializable` also works if scenario A reads the table before insert, even without extra enumeration column

Comment: Do you see using constraint like ``unique (col)`` and ``ON CONFLICT``  in INSERT?

Comment: Col not unique and there are no conflicts

Comment: Well, the optimistic locking strategy need not re-read the whole table, but only the relavent part (e.g. with `col = 2` and check there is no change as a predicate in the insert (select) statement. If this is not practicable you will have to use *pesimistic* table locking.

Comment: So every time you insert a row in scenario A, you need to compute a subset of data and insert an extra row. That's pretty inefficient. If you need a summary table, use a separate summary table.

Comment: You would need some kind of locking that worked across transactions. For example, you could set or insert a row that says that 2 is "in progress" which would prevent another process touching it.